# How to simulate slowdown in gdb?

Tags: c, concurrency, gdb, valgrind

I have a program with concurrency, and when I run it normally, everything works fine. However, when using `valgrind`, I run into (probably deadlock) issues, most likely because `valgrind` causes the program to run much slower. I tried debugging the program using `gdb`, but again I couldn't reproduce the error. I was wondering if there was some way to make `gdb` run slower so that I could potentially reproduce and find the bug. The program is run on a remote server.

The program is huge with loads of concurrency, so pure code analysis isn't very realistic at this point.

Comment: There are [other tools in the Valgrind suite](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html), a couple of them specifically for multi-threaded programs. I suggest you try them out.

Comment: When you say works fine, do you mean, works fine for now?  Do you anticipate deadlocks on the release software?

Comment: Well it works when I simply run the program. However, naturally this doesn't mean that the code is valid, as concurrency errors can show up in only specific conditions.

@JoachimPileborg thanks, I'll check out DRD and Helgrind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when using valgrind, I run into (probably deadlock) issues,

There is a way to analyze your problem when it happens while running your program under `valgrind`. Use `gdbserver` feature in `valgrind` in order to analyze this deadlock. Run you program under `valgrind`, get a deadlock, then attach `gdb` and investigate your deadlock. This is from valgrind doc:

> A program running under Valgrind is not executed directly by the CPU.
>   Instead it runs on a synthetic CPU provided by Valgrind. This is why a
>   debugger cannot debug your program when it runs on Valgrind.
>
> This section describes how GDB can interact with the Valgrind
>   gdbserver to provide a fully debuggable program under Valgrind.

So you need to run your program under valgrind in this way:

```
valgrind --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 prog
```

And as soon as you get a deadlock, attach to it under gdb according to instructions here: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver.

I think if you have indeed a deadlock, then you need to run `thread apply all backtrace` in gdb then.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use the [`helgrind` valgrind plugin](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html). It is a thread-error detector and can help you to discover inconsistent lock ordering (source of deadlocks).

Another way to do this is to place `sleep` call inside the source code of your critical sections. But it's a little dirty.

Comment: Helgrind reported, suffice to say, a rather bountiful amount of errors. This is the best line of investigation at this point. I don't know the Stack Overflow protocol that well, so I'm not sure if I should mark this as accepted answer. It helped, but it doesn't precisely answer the question, so...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run gdb and valgrind simultaneously, suggested by valgrind at startup, though I didn't notice it at first:

```
==16218== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==16218==   /path/to/gdb ./ha3_qdqx.exe
==16218== and then give GDB the following command
==16218==   target remote | /path/to/valgrind/bin/vgdb --pid=16218
==16218== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
```